# Need HTML alignment tips

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I'm writing a Chrome extension and I'm specifically concerned about the HTML layout in one of my pages. So far I have something very simple. I have a table that is dynamically altered in javascript and it needs to stay on the left. I also have a DIV which will be the container for a whole set of other controls, like edit fields and buttons. I want this main DIV to appear to the right of the table.

Everything I've tried so far has failed to get that DIV to the right of my table. As it currently stands, my DIV is below the table. I've heard that using float works, but this seems hacky and has a funny side effects. Maybe I don't really understand HTML layouts yet, even though I've read about them. I wish it worked more like Winforms where I could just tell something where to go. In any case, if someone could help educate me as to the best and cleanest method of achieving my desired layout, I'd appreciate it. My code is below:

```
<body>
    <div id="logged_in">
        <table id="contact_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Contact Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="interface">
            <p>Here are instructions.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note that in the above code, the DIV with the id 'interface' should be on the right of the table with id 'contact_table'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a float is exactly what you should do here.

```
<table id="contact_table" style="float:left">
```

You'll probably also need this:

```
<div style="clear:left"></div>
```

right before your `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of the full scope of the layout but you have many, many options.  here are two:

1. (not compliant) replace the "logged_in" div with a table with the username/password as a nested table inside the left TD as you currently have it and your interface controls in a separate TD on the right.
2. Add a float:left to the table and a float:left to the interface div and control it's positioning with margin-left

Answer (score 0):

Your divs should both be set to float:left;

This isn't hacky at all, it's just how you get divs to display next to one another (display:inline may work as well) - however you always need to be sure to clear your blocks (assuming class='fl' means float:left and class='ff' means clear:both;):

```
<div class='fl><!--table--></div><div class='fl'><!--other content--></div>
<div class='ff'><!--clear the float block--></div>
```

That should get you started - good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried float:left (without the clear) and I mentioned it felt hacky because when I modified the left margin of the DIV, it didn't indent it. I found out this is because your margin has to be greater than the width of the table, which I thought was kind of broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div id="logged_in">
    <table id="contact_table", style="float:left;">
        <tr>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="interface">
        <p>Here are instructions.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would put the instructions on the right of the contact_table.

I'd look at a layout system like Blueprint: http://blueprintcss.org/ It's really good for controlling object alignment and you don't have to always rely on tables.